# SQL query, how to get a row that doesn't exist?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, `PRODUCTS` and `STOCK`. I need a query that can get all products stock, but if a product doesn't have stock, the table `STOCK` don't have the row for the product.

tables exemplo:
[image: PRODUCT and STOCK table]

query I try:

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.product,
  b.stock
FROM product a,
     stock b
WHERE a.id = b.id                              
ORDER BY a.id
```

Result of this query:

[image]

I need the query return this result:

[image]

tks for attention guys =]]]]

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and **easier to convert to outer join** if needed!

Comment: outer joins are designed exactly for this

Comment: Use [left join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: Tip 2: `COALESCE()`!

Comment: Also, `a` and `b` are poor table aliases. Choose something that makes sense, like `p` for `products`.

Answer (score 1):

Left Join and NVL() ...

```sql
WITH
    products (ID, PRODUCT) AS
        (
            Select 1, 'aaa' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'bbb' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'ccc' From Dual Union All
            Select 4, 'ddd' From Dual Union All
            Select 5, 'eee' From Dual Union All
            Select 6, 'fff' From Dual Union All
            Select 7, 'ggg' From Dual Union All
            Select 8, 'hhh' From Dual Union All
            Select 9, 'iii' From Dual 
        ),
    stocks (ID, STOCK) AS
        (
            Select 1, 10 From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 12 From Dual Union All
            Select 4,  5 From Dual Union All
            Select 5, 55 From Dual Union All
            Select 6,  3 From Dual Union All
            Select 9, 22 From Dual 
        )
Select      p.ID, p.PRODUCT, Nvl(s.STOCK, 0) "STOCK"
From        products p
Left Join   stocks s ON (s.ID = p.ID)
Order By    p.ID
    
        ID PRODUCT      STOCK
---------- ------- ----------
         1 aaa             10 
         2 bbb              0 
         3 ccc             12 
         4 ddd              5 
         5 eee             55 
         6 fff              3 
         7 ggg              0 
         8 hhh              0 
         9 iii             22
```